# just first set of my images appear in my list view

Tags: android, listview

I have list view that display items images and when I run my application for example : just first 5 elements photos are displayed (my screen can display just 5 elements) and when I scroll down I cannot see the images of rest elements 
this is my code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemListItem tli;
        if (null == convertView) {
            tli = (ItemListItem) View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list_item, null);

            // I put this code here to get rid of the blocking when user click any category
            Item item = FilteredData.get(position);
            item.convertStringImageToBitmapImage();
        } else {
            tli = (ItemListItem) convertView;
        }

        tli.setItem(FilteredData.get(position));
        return tli;
    }
```

convertStringImageToBitmapImage(); is simple method that convert my image from string to bitmap

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrote **item.convertStringImageToBitmapImage();** in if condition means this will call when your convertview is null. Write this code outside of condition.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemListItem tli;
        if (null == convertView) {
            tli = (ItemListItem) View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list_item, null);

            // I put this code here to get rid of the blocking when user click any category

        } else {
            tli = (ItemListItem) convertView;
        }
            Item item = FilteredData.get(position);
            item.convertStringImageToBitmapImage();
        tli.setItem(FilteredData.get(position));
        return tli;
```

Comment: why convertView didn't contain my image !

Comment: convertview is null firsttime but when you scroll it is not null. that's why